# looking for other ways to Prevent Panning and Zooming on blackberry 10

Tags: javascript, web-applications, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I'm building js application on top of BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK and i'm looking other whys to prevent Panning and zooming behavior.
I tried the ios method by disable the default touchmove behavior but it cause other bugs that i can afford.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function preventBehavior(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', preventBehavior, false);
    </script>
```

other suggestion ??

Comment: i tried also the css solution -webkit-user-select:none/text but this solution canceled the selections on input fields and cause a clipboard problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the viewport panning/scaling/bouncing you get when not setting up your viewport have a go at this:

I generally add this in the  of my index html file.

```
<!-- set viewport -->
<script>
  var meta = document.createElement("meta");
  meta.setAttribute('name','viewport');
  meta.setAttribute('content','initial-scale='+ (1/window.devicePixelRatio) + ',user-scalable=no');
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
</script>
```